# Magento : Call widget call from phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, programmatically, widgets

I have created Widget and want to call it from `header.phtml`
[image]
In this widget i have called Static block but widget not called.This widget have id 2
i have set code below please help me to correct this or give me another for `id = "2"`

```
$widget = Mage::getModel('cms/widget_block')->load('2');
                    $widgetBlock = $this
                   ->getLayout()
                   ->createBlock($widget->getType(),
                                 $widget->getTitle(),
                                 $widget->getWidgetParameters());
echo $widgetBlock->toHtml();
```

And

```
<?php
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="2"}}');
echo $_widget;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call a widget on header from admin panel create widget page.

Just click on  **Add Layout Update** button and select page you want to display on from **Display On** dropdown,(here if you want to display on all page then select **All Pages**), then from **Block Reference**  select **Page Header** (Or Page header with position) and then from **Widget  Options** select your static block. Save the widget and check on frontend after clean cache.

Comment: it's not display where i want

Comment: did you tried other option of header like `Page Header, Primary, Central Column` and `Page Header, Primary, Left Column` etc?

Comment: yes but i want php code to display

Comment: I didn't get your point

Comment: i mean i cant call exactly where i want by this method i want php code

Comment: if you want to call static block in header than why are you using widget? you can directly call static block in header

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50886/discussion-between-ketankp-borada-and-piyush).